# Java. Деление в столбик. Съезжает вывод в консоль

Tags: java

Кто-нибудь может подсказать почему при делении 1034/15 съезжает вывод в консоль?

```
public class Division {

    private StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    private StringBuffer quotient = new StringBuffer();
    private StringBuffer reminder = new StringBuffer();

    public String createLongDivision(int dividend, int divisor) {

        dividend = Math.abs(dividend);
        divisor = Math.abs(divisor);

        if (divisor == 0) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divisor can't be 0");

        }

        if (dividend < divisor) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dividend can't be less than divisor");

        }

        String[] digits = String.valueOf(dividend).split("");
        Integer reminderNumber;
        Integer multiplyResult;
        Integer divisorDigit = calculateDigit(divisor);
        Integer mod;

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {

            reminder.append(digits[i]);
            reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

            if (reminderNumber >= divisor) {

                mod = reminderNumber % divisor;
                multiplyResult = reminderNumber / divisor * divisor;

                String lastReminder = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", "_" + reminderNumber.toString());
                result.append(lastReminder).append("\n");

                String multiply = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "d", multiplyResult);
                result.append(multiply).append("\n");

                Integer tab = lastReminder.length() - calculateDigit(multiplyResult);
                result.append(createDivisor(reminderNumber, tab)).append("\n");

                quotient.append(reminderNumber / divisor);

                reminder.replace(0, reminder.length(), mod.toString());
                reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

            } 


            if (i == digits.length - 1) {

                result.append(String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", reminderNumber.toString())).append("\n");

            }
        }

        modifyResultView(dividend, divisor);
        return result.toString();

    }

    private String createDivisor (Integer reminderNumber, Integer tab) {

        return assemblyString(tab, ' ') + assemblyString(calculateDigit(reminderNumber), '-');

    }

    private int calculateDigit(int i) {

        return (int) Math.log10(i) + 1;

    }

    private String assemblyString(int numberOfSymbols, char symbol) {

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSymbols; i++) {

            string.append(symbol);

        }

        return string.toString();

    }

    private void modifyResultView(Integer dividend, Integer divisor) {

        int[] index = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

            if (result.charAt(i) == '\n') {

                index[j] = i;

                j++;

            }

            if (j == 3) {

                break;

            }

        }

        int tab = calculateDigit(dividend) + 1 - index[0];
        result.insert(index[2], assemblyString(tab, ' ') + "│" + quotient.toString());
        result.insert(index[1], assemblyString(tab, ' ') + "│" + assemblyString(quotient.length(), '-'));
        result.insert(index[0], "│" + divisor);
        result.replace(1, index[0], dividend.toString());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Division division = new Division();

        System.out.println(division.createLongDivision(1034, 15));

        }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О мой бог. В первые вижу такое) Ну тут понятно что надо дебажить и искать почему оно в строчке после 90 ставит 3 прочерка вместо двух. Остальное не понятно

Comment: Очевидно, когда на очередном шаге делим числа одинаковой разрядности, то все норм. А когда 3-значное на 2-значное , тогда трабл

Comment: Спасибо, дебагер помог.) Нужно было заменить строчку:
result.append(createDivisor(reminderNumber, tab)).append("\n");
на
result.append(createDivisor(multiplyResult, tab)).append("\n");

Answer (score 1):

Я заменил `createDivisor(reminderNumber, tab)` на `createDivisor(multiplyResult, tab)`

```
      Integer tab = lastReminder.length() - calculateDigit(multiplyResult);
      result.append(createDivisor(multiplyResult, tab)).append("\n");
```

также заменил в методе `createDivisor` - `reminderNumber` на `multiplyResult`

```
    private String createDivisor (Integer multiplyResult, Integer tab) {

    return assemblyString(tab, ' ') + assemblyString(calculateDigit(multiplyResult), '-');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Division {

private StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
private StringBuffer quotient = new StringBuffer();
private StringBuffer reminder = new StringBuffer();

public String createLongDivision(int dividend, int divisor) {

    dividend = Math.abs(dividend);
    divisor = Math.abs(divisor);

    if (divisor == 0) {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divisor can't be 0");

    }

    if (dividend < divisor) {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dividend can't be less than divisor");

    }

    String[] digits = String.valueOf(dividend).split("");
    Integer reminderNumber;
    Integer multiplyResult;
    Integer divisorDigit = calculateDigit(divisor);
    Integer mod;

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {

        reminder.append(digits[i]);
        reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

        if (reminderNumber >= divisor) {

            mod = reminderNumber % divisor;
            multiplyResult = reminderNumber / divisor * divisor;

            String lastReminder = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", "_" + reminderNumber.toString());
            result.append(lastReminder).append("\n");

            String multiply = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "d", multiplyResult);
            result.append(multiply).append("\n");

            Integer tab = lastReminder.length() - calculateDigit(multiplyResult);
            result.append(createDivisor(multiplyResult, tab)).append("\n");

            quotient.append(reminderNumber / divisor);

            reminder.replace(0, reminder.length(), mod.toString());
            reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

        } 


        if (i == digits.length - 1) {

            result.append(String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", reminderNumber.toString())).append("\n");

        }
    }

    modifyResultView(dividend, divisor);
    return result.toString();

}

private String createDivisor (Integer multiplyResult, Integer tab) {

    return assemblyString(tab, ' ') + assemblyString(calculateDigit(multiplyResult), '-');

}

private int calculateDigit(int i) {

    return (int) Math.log10(i) + 1;

}

private String assemblyString(int numberOfSymbols, char symbol) {

    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSymbols; i++) {

        string.append(symbol);

    }

    return string.toString();

}

private void modifyResultView(Integer dividend, Integer divisor) {

    int[] index = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

        if (result.charAt(i) == '\n') {

            index[j] = i;

            j++;

        }

        if (j == 3) {

            break;

        }

    }

    int tab = calculateDigit(dividend) + 1 - index[0];
    result.insert(index[2], assemblyString(tab, ' ') + "│" + quotient.toString());
    result.insert(index[1], assemblyString(tab, ' ') + "│" + assemblyString(quotient.length(), '-'));
    result.insert(index[0], "│" + divisor);
    result.replace(1, index[0], dividend.toString());

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Division division = new Division();

    System.out.println(division.createLongDivision(1034, 15));

    }

}
```